# Using jwt-decode with typescript front-end project

Tags: typescript, jwt, auth0

Description
I am trying to use jwt-decode in a typescript project i.e. Stencil Project & it is throwing following error:

> This expression is not callable.Type '{ default: (token: string,
>   options?: Options) => TTokenDto; }' has no call signatures.

```
import * as jwt_decode from 'jwt-decode';
.
.
.
let token = "........";
let decoded = jwt_decode(token);
```

**Reproduction**

- install jwt-decode in any typescript project npm install --save
  @types/jwt-decode npm install --save jwt-decode import it in your
  code & use import * as jwt_decode from 'jwt-decode'; . . . let token
  = "........"; let decoded = jwt_decode(token);
- build project
- Version of this library used: ^2.2.0 Version of the platform or
- framework used, if applicable: stencil - ^1.3.3 , typescript - 3.7.2

Comment: `import jwt_decode from 'jwt-decode';`?

Comment: @zerkms Thanks a lot man. It worked like a charm for me. I write that incorrect import as official documentation only specify require based import & just guessed that default import will work as is!

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Following correction to the import statement works fine:

```
import jwt_decode from 'jwt-decode';
```

**Update (November 2023):** As pointed out in the comments, the package `jwt-decode` no loger has a default export.
Therefore the correct import statement is now:

```
import { jwtDecode } from 'jwt-decode';
```

Comment: NOTE: for anyone reading this in 2023 or later that package seems to [no longer have a default export](https://github.com/auth0/jwt-decode/blob/main/lib/index.ts) you will need to import a named export instead.

Answer (score 2):

For Angular 17 and newer you will need to import a named export instead (as @Jared Smith said)

```
import { jwtDecode } from 'jwt-decode';
```

Answer (score 0):

As said by Nico you have to import a named export instead, using Angular 17 and newer. However I had to use the slightly different line of code for making it run properly:

```
import {jwtDecode } from 'jwt-decode';
```