# jwt-decode "This expression is not callable." with typscript

Tags: typescript, react-native, jwt, expo

Just started seeing this error.

I know this is related to the question here: [Using jwt-decode with typescript front-end project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59280632/using-jwt-decode-with-typescript-front-end-project)

However, I already am trying the answer and it's not working...

[image]

### The Code

```
import jwt from 'jwt-decode';

export function isTokenExpired(token: string): boolean {
  // check token payload
  const tokenPayload: any = jwt(token);
  // check token expiration date in payload
  const tokenExpiration = tokenPayload.exp;
  const now = Math.floor(new Date().getTime() / 1000); // token exp shaved off milliseconds
  // if (expiration date is greater than current date)
  return now > tokenExpiration;
}
```

### The Error

```
This expression is not callable.
  Type 'typeof import("c:/Projects/msal-react-native-expo/node_modules/jwt-decode/build/cjs/index")' has no call signatures.ts(2349)`
```

Note: I'm using this same code snippet in a react project and it's working fine. However, this seems to be breaking in my react-native/expo project. Not sure if it's a dom related issue or what the deal is. Is there an alternative solution?

Comment: That package [doesn't have a default export](https://github.com/auth0/jwt-decode/blob/main/lib/index.ts) please read the documentation before posting, since it clearly [imports a named export](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jwt-decode#usage). The answer you linked is 5 years old, and must have been for a much earlier version of the library.

Comment: I left a comment on that answer so hopefully the next person doesn't have the same issue.

Comment: Looks like they changed this with version 4.0.0. All I did was revert the version back to 3.1.2 and it works. I don't think this deserves a -1 vote, as most developers will search this issue as this change will break many production builds. And the first thing many devs will do is google the question.

Comment: "most developers will search this issue as this change will break many production builds" most developers pin their versions, at least to the minor, for exactly this sort of situation. "The first thing many devs will do is google the question" I don't think it's too much to ask that people *do the most cursory glance possibly at the documentation of the thing they are using* (it's literally above the fold on the package page on npm) before posting a question about it. Back in the day that would earn the poster a very salty "RTFM". I personally think *that* is too harsh, but it isn't *wrong*.

Comment: In the package.json, some library package versions have a caret next to the version number during npm install, this will automatically update the version and packages during npm install. When majority of developers take already working code, change nothing, and see the error in the ide, they will tend to google why it broke before going back to re-read the entire documentation of that library. I agree teams shouldn't update unless it's supported, but this isn't always the case. I also agree maybe I should have re-read the docs. But I think this will help people.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

https://github.com/auth0/jwt-decode/blob/main/CHANGELOG.md#migration-to-v400

Migration to v4.0.0

The `jwtDecode` function is now no longer the default export, and is instead provided as a named export. Make sure to update your code in places where you are importing this function:

```
-import jwtDecode from "jwt-decode";
+import { jwtDecode } from "jwt-decode";
```

Comment: Thanks, this works. I also noticed the version difference (4.0.0 vs 3.1.2). For anyone reading this, it's optional to revert and keep the old code, however going forward, we should always use the most up to date solutions.